# Null argument error when updating Maven project

Tags: java, maven, configuration, null, arguments

I'm trying to update my multimodule Maven project by right clicking the project in "Project Explorer" and selecting "Maven" -> "Update". Then I get the messeage

> Could not update project NAME configuration: null argument

[image]

The other projects update normally whithout errors. 
What can I do in this case?

Edit: I'm using Eclipse Mars

Comment: try delete the .settings folder and .project file in the project and then reimport the project.

Comment: It doesnt solve the problem. After reimporting it I'm encountering the same  problem...

Answer (score 17):

I had the exact same problem. The .log entries are a very good hint (location: `workspace/.metadata/.log`). The solution was to go into Window/Preferences then navigate to Maven/Java EE Integration. Turn off the "JPA Configurator" option.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. Looking at `workspace/.metadata/.log` the stack trace mentioned `JpaFacetDataModelProvider`. Then I remember I turned off the JPA facet in my project due to some other earlier problem. Re-enabling the JPA facet made the Maven issue go away. The JPA error I had earlier didn't come back, so lucky me.

Comment: Helped here as well.  Wonder if there is a bug reported for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for me was to configure a new worspace. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. If you load the "Error Log" view from "Window->Show View" you might be able to see the list of errors. Double-clicking the error will give a stack-trace with Session Data.

[Event Details from double-click on Error Log view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3fqw.png)

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product 
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```